# How can alternate the background colors of my items in the recycler view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to alternate background colors for my items in recycler view for odd and even items. I tried doing it in the onBindViewHolder method of the Adapter class, but it does not work.

Below is the code.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ReportViewHolder holder, int position) {

        ReportItem currentItem = reportlist.get(position);

        if(position%2==0){
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.teal));

        } else {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.lightteal));

        }

        holder.departureDate.setText((currentItem.getDepartureDate()));
        holder.flightNumber.setText(currentItem.getFlightNumber());
```

Below is the xml code for the holder layout.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="@color/teal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        >

        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           
            android:textColor="@color/white"
/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: in both cases you used the same color (R.color.white) try to change the second color

Comment: sorry, I was testing something with white, i have changed the colors above, it still does not work

Comment: try with this : `holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.white));`

Comment: I tried, it does not work

Comment: which view container you used in your Holder Layout?

Comment: I am just using itemView

Comment: I updated the code above with the whole adapter code

Comment: can you share your Holder Layout please

Comment: what do you exactly mean by holder layout?

Comment: The XML file which contains the two TextView

Comment: where can i share it?

Comment: i have too less points for chat

Comment: yes you can update your question

Comment: I just updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `holder.relativeLayout` instead of `holder.itemView`

Comment: You need to declare the relativelayout on your holder class like the tow text view you uesd

Comment: Your issue is when you declare match parent in your relativeLayout that mean all your cardView is hidden by the relativelayout that all

Comment: Also in your  old code you can set transparent color in your relativeLayout and let the card view take effect